# Kubuntu - KDE No option for Open Terminal Here in Desktop

Tags: command-line, gnome, kubuntu, kde, cinnamon

I don't mean in Dolphin; I mean on the desktop, like in GNOME or Cinnamon Is there a method to integrate it or create a custom solution, such as linking to a personal option that would execute a shell script to open the terminal in a specified direction?
[image]

Comment: Can you please ***EDIT*** your question and describe what this feature is? How can it be on the desktop? What does this feature look like in Gnome or Cinnamon? I use Cinnamon but I don't understand what it is you are looking for.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I did add a image and answered Archisman Panigrahi what i meant. I Think it should be clear now. I cant open a Terminal directly by rightclicking on the real Desktop, where ur background Image is. It works on Desktop Folder in Dolphin but i tried to say i dont mean that Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be a bit unclear to me, so I am adding solutions for both Dolphin and the Desktop.

Firstly, you can always open a terminal with `ctrl + alt + T`.

### Desktop

Add the `Console Profiles` widget to the desktop - `Add Widgets -> Console Profiles`. Clicking the profile will open up a terminal.

[image]

(you can rename the profile name to "Open Terminal", instead of `Profile 1`)

### Dolphin

Go to `Settings -> Configure Toolbar` and Add `Open Terminal Here` to current actions.

[image]

Now you can open a terminal in any folder.

Comment: "The question seems to be a bit unclear to me, so I am adding solutions for both Dolphin and the Desktop."
I just wanted to open a Terminal by rightclicking (on my Desktop), i know people gonna write its already there because its in Dolphin. But i mean the real Desktop where ur Background Image is. 
Not the Dolphin Folder called Desktop. Its possible in other Distros/Desktop Enviroments

Comment: @onur.zn You can add a terminal widget to the real desktop, as described in my answer